# Select/filter JSON by date_time value starts with

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to create a new JSON object containing the two items in this source JSON, where the 'date_time' value starts with '2015-09-21'. This should return items 160 and 161 (excluding 162). Here is the JSON:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "item":{
            "number":"160",
            "name":"Project example phase 2",
            "estimated_duration":{
               "duration_minutes":0.0
            },
            "remaining_duration":{
               "duration_minutes":0.0
            },
            "customer":{
               "company_name":null,
               "id":null
            },
            "reported_by_customer_contact":{
               "name":"",
               "id":null
            },
            "item_type":"features",
            "id":160
         },
         "user":{
            "name":"Joe Bloggs",
            "id":31
         },
         "work_log_type":{
            "name":"Architecture",
            "id":1
         },
         "work_done":{
            "duration_minutes":120.0,
            "time_unit":{
               "abbreviation":"min",
               "name":"Minutes",
               "id":1
            },
            "text":"120 min",
            "duration":120.0
         },
         "id":263,
         "description":"Testing",
         "date_time":"2015-09-21T13:48:00Z"
      },
      {
         "item":{
            "number":"161",
            "name":"Project abc",
            "estimated_duration":{
               "duration_minutes":0.0
            },
            "remaining_duration":{
               "duration_minutes":0.0
            },
            "customer":{
               "company_name":"Universal Exports",
               "id":2
            },
            "reported_by_customer_contact":{
               "name":"Mark Zuckerstein",
               "id":3
            },
            "item_type":"incidents",
            "id":1
         },
         "user":{
            "name":"Joe Bloggs",
            "id":31
         },
         "work_log_type":{
            "name":"Analysis",
            "id":2
         },
         "work_done":{
            "duration_minutes":300.0,
            "time_unit":{
               "abbreviation":"hrs",
               "name":"Hours",
               "id":2
            },
            "text":"5 hrs",
            "duration":5.0
         },
         "id":248,
         "description":"Stupid coffee cup",
         "date_time":"2015-09-21T11:28:00Z"
      },
      {
         "item":{
            "number":"162",
            "name":"I broke my cup holder",
            "estimated_duration":{
               "duration_minutes":0.0
            },
            "remaining_duration":{
               "duration_minutes":0.0
            },
            "customer":{
               "company_name":"Universal Exports",
               "id":2
            },
            "reported_by_customer_contact":{
               "name":"Mark Zuckerstein",
               "id":3
            },
            "item_type":"incidents",
            "id":1
         },
         "user":{
            "name":"Joe Bloggs",
            "id":31
         },
         "work_log_type":{
            "name":"Architecture",
            "id":1
         },
         "work_done":{
            "duration_minutes":10.0,
            "time_unit":{
               "abbreviation":"min",
               "name":"Minutes",
               "id":1
            },
            "text":"10 min",
            "duration":10.0
         },
         "id":249,
         "description":"Trying to fix his cup holder",
         "date_time":"2015-09-22T11:33:00Z"
      }
   ],
   "metadata":{
      "total_count":3,
   }
}
```

I started to play with lodash but quickly got out of my depth after filtering for the actual time and trying to combine the 'filter' with other lodash functions.

```
var filtered = _.filter(object.data, { date_time: "2015-09-21T13:48:00Z"});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use lodash. You can use the `Array.prototype.filter` method. `Array.prototype.filter` method for filtering the array and `String.prototype.indexOf` method for checking the index of that specific string.

```
yourVariable.data.filter(function(el) { 
    return el.date_time.indexOf('2015-09-21') === 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var final = [];
var by = "2015-09-21";

_.map(data.data, function(o){
    if (o.date_time.match(by + ".*")) {
        final.push(o);
     }
});

console.log(final);
```